# Word for a hope for something that is unlikely to happen

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases, science, emotions

What is a word that can be used to describe the feeling of looking forward to something that probably will not happen? preferably one that might refer to an experiment

Comment: **forlorn** might be a useful word.

Comment: Please provide some information about what type of word (verb, noun, etc.) you're looking for as well as a sample sentence showing how you would use the word you're looking for (put an X or ___ where the word would go).  Also, what words have you considered and why did they not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Wishing (present continuous tense) fits well enough:

***[Wish](http://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/wish-1)***

> Feel or express a strong desire or hope for something that is not
>   easily attainable; want something that cannot or probably will not
>   happen...

-- Encyclopedia.com

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is **pipe dream**, defined at [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pipe%20dream) as:

> an illusory or fantastic plan, hope, or story; a hope, wish, or dream that is impossible to achieve or not practical.

The link above also gives the supposed origin, as "from the fantasies brought about by the smoking of opium."  See also Wikpedia's article on [opium pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opium_pipe).

Answer (score 0):

“Apprehensiveness” comes close if there’s a feeling of mild anxiety accompanying the anticipation.

If you're not limited to one word, you can say, “I have reservations about its likelihood.”